# onkeydown in Sencha touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2, dom-events, keyboard-events

Javascript has [three events](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp) for key presses, keyup, keypress and keydown. 
For some reason Sencha Touch only supports they keyup event. I want to catch the event (probably keydown or keypress) before it changes the value in the textfield. Catching the keydown event would make this possible, also it should be a lot faster. With keyup the effect is a bit slow.

Finally the goal is to allow the user to only enter number and add decimal and thousand separators automatically. That's currently possible with the keyup event, but slow. As a user you can see the text changing and then being changed again.

My code for adding the keydown event to the textfield:

```
initialize: function()
{
    this.down('textfield[name=amountTotal]').onkeydown
    = MyApp.app.getController('MyController').handleInput;
}
```

I've checked that when this code executes the textfield is found and the controller function does hold the correct function that I want to execute. I've also added the function to my view file.

Yet it won't reach my handleInput function.

I know Sencha [does not support other events](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?268391-How-to-listen-and-prevent-a-keydown-keypress-in-a-textareafield), but this should be possible with just pure Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it.

```
initialize: function() {
    var textfield = this.down('textfield[name=amountTotal]');
    textfield.bodyElement.dom.onkeydown = MyApp.app.getController('MyController').handleInput;
}
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/caj

Comment: Thanks that works, the only downside is that I don't get the sencha textfield as an argument directly. So how to find that? I can't use a selector based on the name because there's a list of fields like this one.